# Having an issue getting a successful multisite installation for Drupal 8 using BLT

Tags: drupal, vagrant, drupal-8

I am currently having an issue to get a proper working multisite configuration using BLT 9. I have added the vhosts and the databases and users to `box/config.yml` ran `vagrant provision` to make the changes.

I now ran `blt recipes:mutisite:init` and entered the information into the wizard. This creates a multisite directory structure in `docroot/sites/example`.

When I run `blt setup --define site=example` it is *not* installing into the secondary database I have created in DrupalVM but instead uses the default 'drupal' database.

I have tried many different things based on what I have read from the online documentation but cannot seem to get a functioning multisite install with it's own proper drush alias linked to the second database. How do I complete this setup?

Comment: I guess you are better off asking for suport on GitHub: https://github.com/acquia/blt